# What does the 奈 in 神奈川県 mean?

Tags: meaning, kanji

What does the 奈 in 神奈川県 mean? I saw the term listed as what on Jisho. One person sent me the definition of an altar and others say that it has no meaning just a sound.

Comment: In particular, which part of your friends said definition are you not content with. It's insufficient? I can't find other explanations easily.

Comment: I chatted  with Japanese people online, and received a few different answers, most commonly its for pronunciation only, but I wanted to obtain a definite answer, if possible.

Comment: There seems to be several hypothesis. [神奈川県の地名の由来・語源を解説。](http://chimei-allguide.com/14/000.html) . That might not be a definite one though.

Comment: Probably the Japanese pronunciation of a Chinese character, maybe bearing up, enduring?   https://dictionary.hantrainerpro.com/chinese-english/translation-nai_bear.htm

Comment: https://www.mdbg.net/chinese/dictionary?popup=1&wdqchssp=神奈川县&wdrst=0 in  Chinese, the character means how can one help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I adopt the hypothesis in the site [神奈川県 - 地名由来辞典](http://chimei-allguide.com/14/000.html).

*この地に水源地が解からない川があり、「上無川（かみなしがわ）」と呼ばれていたため「神奈川」になったとする説。* "*There were the river with the water source was unknown called 上無川{かみなしがわ} changed into 神奈川{かながわ}.*"

And my hypothesis is there were not so many rivers in the past. Therefore, they were often seeking the water source and found it important things. Then I have decided to look up the number of rivers by prefectures.

According to the site [数字で見る「日本の自然資源」月刊事業構想 編集部](https://www.projectdesign.jp/201612/natural-treasure/003272.php),

There are rankings in the page: ***日本全国で川の数は、35,260に上り、一級河川の総延長＊は88,000kmに及ぶ***. 神奈川 is ranked No6 from the bottom in it. 石川 is No5 from the bottom. 香川 is No2 from the bottom.

[image]

一級河川の指定区間と指定区間外の合計数値 出典）国土交通省、一級河川の河川延長等調 ＊都道府県別（平成27年4月30日現在)

And looking up the origin of [香川県 - 地名由来辞典](http://chimei-allguide.com/37/000.html)　*古来より雨量が少なく、夏期に水枯れする河川が多かったことから、「かれかわ（枯川）」が転じて「かがわ」になったとする説。* Since long time ago, the amount of water is small. Therefore, there were many rivers dried up in the summer. Probably 「かれかわ（枯川）」: *dried river* changed into 香川{かがわ} because of that.

石川県 seems a little bit different [石川県 - 地名由来辞典](http://chimei-allguide.com/17/000.html). *県最大の河川である「手取川」は、上流から石を多く流すことから通称「石川」と言った。*. 手取川{てどりがわ}, the largest river in the prefecture. Since it sheds many stones from upstream, it has changed so-called 石川{いしかわ} according to the [wikipedia : 手取川](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E6%89%8B%E5%8F%96%E5%B7%9D) This time, the river was violent and needed to be paid attention.Prpbably That's why the river was called like that.

For 神奈川, I guess you can't pick up only 奈{な} kanji element. Hence 神奈{かな} is at least an ateji in 神奈川{かながわ}.